# include native library for android using ant build.xml

Tags: java, android, opencv, ant

I'm trying to bundle a native library in my android project so that my app doesn't crash whenever it tries to access the library. The library that I'm trying to bundle is called `opencv_java246.so`

Since this is an existing project which was originally designed and developed for non-android systems and later extended to work for android, the project in eclipse isn't an android project.

Right now, the exception that I'm getting is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(32760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(32760): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at com.acunia.fleet.docuscan.android.DocuScanActivity.onActivityResult(DocuScanActivity.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.<clinit>(Highgui.java:313)
E/AndroidRuntime(32760):    ... 14 more
```

I looked up how to manually install the library on my android but was unable to find anything that worked because my android isn't rooted and I can't copy the file to my androids filesystem.

```
shell@android:/ $ mkdir libs
mkdir failed for libs, Read-only file system
```

I have tried to create folders in my existing project called `/lib/armeabi`, `/libs/armeabi` and `/libs/libs/armeabi` but none of them include the native library to my apk.

I have tried using an `Android.mk` file and it puts my .so library in `/lib/armeabi` but when I build the apk, it still can't find the library (I don't know if it even included the library in the apk).

Here is the ant build target:

```
  <target name="apk" depends="unpack">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/class" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/java" />

    <filter token="fleet-android-sar.version" value="${fleet-android-sar.version}" />
    <filter token="fleet-android-sar.versioncode" value="${fleet-android-sar.versioncode}" />
    <copy todir="${build.dir}" filtering="true">
      <fileset dir="${resource.dir}" includes="AndroidManifest.xml" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${build.dir}/class" filtering="false">
      <fileset dir="${library.class.dir}/">
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/docuscan/android/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/geofence/common/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/geofence/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/logbook/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/logbook/android/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/logbook/motion/*" />
        <exclude name="com/acunia/fleet/logbook/motion/MotionAnalyzer*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/messenger/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/messenger/common/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/messenger/agent/MessageListener*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/messenger/agent/TextMessage*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/planningassistant/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/planningassistant/common/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/reporting/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/desktop/impl/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/desktop/pairing/**" />
        <exclude name="com/acunia/fleet/reporting/AWTReportView*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/reporting/android/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/reporting/common/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/reporting/impl/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/reporting/impl/ReportActivator*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/session/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/session/android/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/session/impl/*" />
        <exclude name="com/acunia/fleet/session/Identification*" />
        <exclude name="com/acunia/fleet/session/Identificator*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/scanner/android/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/scanner/common/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/filetransfer/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/filetransfer/android/**" />
        <include name="org/osgi/framework/*" />
        <include name="org/osgi/service/cm/*" />
        <include name="org/osgi/service/log/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/otf/agent/android/*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/otf/net/android/node/msg/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/otf/net/node/msg/mux/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/otf/net/share/msg/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/util/net/node/logtransfer/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/util/net/android/logtransfer/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/auth/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/tracking/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/tracking/common/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/state/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/state/common/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/fleet/state/controller/listener/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/logging/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/logging/http/client/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/android/util/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/android/widget/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/osgi/local/Log.class" />
        <include name="com/acunia/time/**" />
        <include name="com/google/zxing/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/zxing/**" />
        <include name="javax/microedition/io/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/util/remoteterm/client/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/util/remoteterm/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/lbs/Address.class" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/lbs/Coordinate.class" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/position/android/**" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/position/nmea/NMEAParser*" />
        <include name="com/acunia/service/position/nmea/NMEAPositionHandler*"/>
        <include name="org/opencv/**"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>

    <exec executable="${aapt}" failonerror="true" taskname="aapt">
      <arg value="package" />
      <arg value="-f" />
      <arg value="-M" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/AndroidManifest.xml" />
      <arg value="-F" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/android-resources.jar" />
      <arg value="-I" />
      <arg value="${library.release.dir}/${android.jar}" />
      <arg value="-S" />
      <arg value="${resource.dir}/res" />
      <arg value="-m" />
      <arg value="-J" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/java" />
    </exec>

    <javac srcdir="${build.dir}/java" debug="false" deprecation="false" includeAntRuntime="no" includeJavaRuntime="no" destdir="${build.dir}/class">
      <bootclasspath>
        <pathelement location="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${java.home}/lib/ext/" includes="**/*.jar" />
      </bootclasspath>
    </javac>

    <exec executable="${dx}" failonerror="true" taskname="dx">
      <arg value="--dex" />
      <arg value="--no-locals" />
      <arg value="--verbose" />
      <arg value="--output=${build.dir}/classes.dex" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/class" />
    </exec>
    <copy file="${build.dir}/android-resources.jar" toFile="${build.dir}/fleetxps-orig.apk"/>
    <zip destfile="${build.dir}/fleetxps-orig.apk" keepcompression="true" update="true" basedir="${build.dir}" includes="classes.dex"/>
    <exec executable="jarsigner" failonerror="true" taskname="jarsigner">
      <arg value="-keystore" />
      <arg value="testkeystore" />
      <arg value="-storepass" />
      <arg value="acunia" />
      <arg value="-keypass" />
      <arg value="acunia" />
      <arg value="-signedjar" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/fleetxps-signed.apk" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/fleetxps-orig.apk" />
      <arg value="acunia" />
    </exec>
    <exec executable="${zipalign}" failonerror="true" taskname="zipalign">
      <arg value="-f" />
      <arg value="4" />
      <arg value="${build.dir}/fleetxps-signed.apk" />
      <arg value="${release.lib.dir}/fleetxps.apk" />
    </exec>
  </target>


<target name="sar" depends="apk">
  <filter token="fleet-android.version" value="${xps-android-sar.version}" />
  <filter token="component.version" value="${component.version}" />
  <filter token="component.build.tag" value="${component.build.tag}" />
  <copy todir="${build.dir}" filtering="true">
    <fileset dir="${resource.dir}/" includes="xps-android.xml" />
  </copy>

  <sar destfile="${release.lib.dir}/fleet-android-${xps-android-sar.version}.sar" provisioning="${build.dir}/xps-android.xml">
    <clientbundle name="sar.tgt">
      <fileset dir="${release.lib.dir}" type="application/x-apk">
        <include name="xps.apk" />
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="${library.resource.dir}/config" type="application/x-osgi-config">
        <include name="com.otf.agent.adapter.diff.config" />
        <include name="com.otf.net.node.ioprovider.otfdatagram.config" />
        <include name="com.messenger.agent.config.config" />
        <include name="com.messenger.agent.list.config" />
        <include name="com.reporting.config" />
        <include name="com.filetransfer.config" />
        <include name="com.scanner.config" />
        <include name="com.reporting.store.config" />
        <include name="com.service.auth.agent.module.basic.config" />
        <include name="com.state.controller.StateController.config" />
        <include name="com.service.tracking.osgi.impl.RealTimeTrackingAgent.config" />
        <include name="com.service.tracking.osgi.impl.TrackingAgent.config" />
        <include name="com.service.logging.buffers.config" />
        <include name="com.service.logging.http.client.config" />
      </fileset>
    </clientbundle>
  </sar>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="apk, redeploy" />

<target name="redeploy">
  <exec executable="${adb}" failonerror="true" taskname="adb">
    <!-- <arg value="-d" /> -->
    <arg value="install" />
    <arg value="-r" />
    <arg value="${release.lib.dir}/xps.apk" />
  </exec>
</target>
```

Is there a way to bundle my native library with my apk using this ant build file? Or any other way that works would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you end up figuring out the issue??